# How to instantiate a class just after starting Django server and access its members later in views.py

Tags: django, django-views

I want to define a class `PacketCount` in Django.

```
class PacketCount:
    def __init__():
        self.count_pkts = 0
    def count_pkts():
        #logic to count the number of packets
```

I want to instantiate the object of `PacketClass` and continuously run the function `count_pkts()` just after starting starting the Django server using the command `python manage.py runserver`.

views.py contains the following function:

```
def index(request):
    # access PacketCountObj.count_pkts
    # return HttpResponse to display the value of PacketCountObj.count_pkts
```

urls.py contains the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

I am unable to figure out a way to automatically instantiate PacketCount class, call `PacketCountObj.count_pkts()` (possibly using a thread) on starting the Django server and then access `PacketCountObj.count_pkts` inside the views.py.
I do not want to use databases, django sessions etc.

Comment: answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72615390/how-to-create-a-class-just-after-starting-django-server-and-access-its-members-l/72615511#72615511